# como poner un menu encima de una imagen que tiene la propiedad absolute y el padre la propiedad relative

Tags: css

Tengo este bloqueo, espero puedan ayudarme.

Cómo poner un menú encima de una imagen que tiene la propiedad `absolute` y el padre la propiedad `relative`?

```css
//img
.figure {
    position: relative;
    height: 255px;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 315px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.capa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

Comment: Hola y bievenido. Faltan detalles en tu pregunta para poder reproducirla en el snippet. Por favor agrega el código `HTML`. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la comunidad.